# ExtractToDirectory , how to extract a zip folder within a zip folder using c#

Tags: c#, zip, unzip, extract

**Problem:** I have this code that extracts all .zip folder inside a specified directory. Now my problem here is that my .zip files contains another .zip file inside of it. The output of my program is it creates a folder for the zip file extracted with a naming structure like this `NUMBER_ + ZipFileName` , now when I open the folder, it still contains a .zip folder inside. How do I extract a zip folder within a zip folder on the same NUMBER_ + ZipFileName Folder? It's kinda confusing to me.

***desired file structure***

Temp - > number_zipfilename-> [ extracted files here w/o .zip]

number_zipfilename2 - > [extraced files  here w/o .zip]

.....

***output of my script file structure***

Temp - > number_zipfilename -> [extracted files but with .zip ]

number_zipfilename -> [extracted files but with .zip ]

Tried the recursive suggestion, but it creates another folder inside my 
number_zipfilename folder and the .zip file is still inside the folder.

this is my tasks requirements, its kinda hard to grasp.

***this is my script***

```
public void extractZipFiles(string targetFileDirectory, string zipFileDirectory, string Number)
{
            Directory.GetFiles(zipFileDirectory, "*.zip", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList()
            .ForEach(zipFilePath => {
                var test = Number + "_" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(zipFilePath);
                var extractPathForCurrentZip = Path.Combine(targetFileDirectory, test);
                if(!Directory.Exists(extractPathForCurrentZip))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(extractPathForCurrentZip);
                }
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFilePath, extractPathForCurrentZip);
            });
}
```

Comment: do you want to recursively unzip? like ... call your routine again for every unzipped zip file? ... oh and by the way ... are you aware of 42.zip? it's a 42KB zip file containing zip files that expands to roughly 4.5 petabyte if unzipped recursively ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 thanks for the heads up! this trial only consists of .zip files though, thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per what I see in your code, I think you should call the `extractZipFiles` method recursively, so that after the extracting you call the method again with the directory where you extracted the files so it scans it for `*.zip` files.

I'm not sure about what variables you'd want to use, but something like this:

```
public void extractZipFiles(string targetFileDirectory, string zipFileDirectory, string Number)
{
            Directory.GetFiles(zipFileDirectory, "*.zip", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList()
            .ForEach(zipFilePath => {
                var test = Number + "_" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(zipFilePath);
                var extractPathForCurrentZip = Path.Combine(targetFileDirectory, test);
                if(!Directory.Exists(extractPathForCurrentZip))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(extractPathForCurrentZip);
                }
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFilePath, extractPathForCurrentZip);
                extractZipFiles(targetFileDirectory, extractPathForCurrentZip, Number);
            });
}
```

Comment: that did the trick! but if possible , how can I edit my code out to be able to save the zip inside my zip file just inside the folder ? Doing it recursively will create another folder for the zip folder inside, I want all the files inside 1 folder... with Number_ + file name. Thank you so much!! I think I need to modify the codes of my method for this to work.

Comment: I just edited my code changing the first param (I think that would do it). Hope it helps!

Comment: appreciate the help bro! and to realizing what I need to do to reach my programming goal. :)  it helped a lot.

Comment: @kebbg nice! if you think that answers your question please would you accept my answer? Glad it helped!

Comment: your suggestion is half way there, but im still not getting to my desired output :( I upvoted your answer though mister devcrp